# Result in row mysql

Tags: mysql

i have this data on my table

```
ID    DATE           TIME       STATE  SIP
'1', '2017-10-31', '10:24:51', 'R', '237'
'2', '2017-10-31', '10:41:35', 'U', '237'
'3', '2017-10-31', '10:45:32', 'R', '611'
'4', '2017-10-31', '10:45:40', 'U', '611'
'5', '2017-10-31', '10:46:03', 'R', '258'
'6', '2017-10-31', '11:10:51', 'R', '237'
'7', '2017-10-31', '11:17:03', 'R', '611'
'8', '2017-10-31', '11:32:21', 'U', '611'
'9', '2017-10-31', '11:32:37', 'R', '611'
'10', '2017-10-31', '11:53:06', 'R', '258'
'11', '2017-10-31', '12:01:24', 'R', '252'
'12', '2017-10-31', '12:01:36', 'U', '611'
'13', '2017-10-31', '12:01:43', 'R', '617'
'14', '2017-10-31', '12:01:57', 'U', '258'
'15', '2017-10-31', '12:02:24', 'R', '611'
'16', '2017-10-31', '12:02:39', 'R', '258'
'17', '2017-10-31', '12:29:09', 'U', '611'
'18', '2017-10-31', '12:31:30', 'R', '611'
'19', '2017-10-31', '12:55:58', 'R', '237'
'20', '2017-10-31', '12:59:58', 'U', '611'
'21', '2017-10-31', '13:00:16', 'U', '252'
'22', '2017-10-31', '13:00:17', 'U', '237'
```

This is my recordset,

i would like to calculate how much time the SIP stay register on system.
state R=Registered U=Unregistered but i don't have a regular login and logout

i would like have:

```
SIP DATE LOGIN LOGOUT
237 2017-10-31 10:24:51 10:41:35
611 2017-10-31 10:45:32 10:45:40
258 2017-10-31 10:46:03 12:01:57
```

and calculate the total time stay connected

thank you for the time you have dedicated to me

Comment: What should be displayed if the user is not logged out yet meaning only one row is there for a `sip`.For i.e. `sip` = `258`

Comment: the last row of result table has 254 as `sip`. Which is not there in table data. And why it should displayed in result when it's logout time is not in the range? Also, in which case `login` should be displayed as `DISCONNECTED`? Please help here.

Comment: Sorry @Harshil my fault i write wrong the sip number

Comment: @Harshil because I thought it was simpler to work on data with bands like time

Comment: i guess you'll get the desired result with my answer. Try that and comment below if it doen't work. Except the `logout` of `258` as it's not in the range given in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution will work:

```
select sip,
     min(time) as login,
    (case when max(time)=min(time) then 'lost'
          else max(time)
     end
    ) as logout
  from SIPregistration 
where time between '10:00:00' and '11:00:00' 
  and state in('R','U') 
group by sip;
```

You can put the text after `THEN` with whatever you want to display in case of there is no logout by an `sip`.

[Click here for the DEMO](http://rextester.com/ABUZ44514)

Comment: thanks a lot for the quickly reply,but in my case for example i had the sip 258 without logout as max(time) and i lost it, ther's any way for display it?

Comment: @user3198961 Dont you get `min(time) = max(time)`  for 258?

Comment: thank you. I'll add the necessary condition to query with the help of OP

Comment: If time is a string, works too. But of course should be DATETIME

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes i get it, but i could be 258 login at 10:45 and logout at 12:30 i work on time range

Comment: @user3198961 Edit your question and show us what result you want, because right now you just ignore 258 in that result, so dont expect we invent a solution.

Comment: yeah...i checked that. I was confused with the date. Min() max() not works when people use string as date in `dd-mm-yy` format. Will update the answer.

Comment: @user3198961 Please try the edited answer and check the demo. Also edit the question with what do you want to do when `login` time is in range given in query but `logout` time is not.

Comment: @Harshil change `time1` column name to `time`

Comment: Hi @Harshil yes it works thanks, i need only to modify the response because as could you see on source table i couldn't work on time range.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want result overlap your range.

First create the SIP ranges:

```
 SELECT s1.sip,
        s1.time as login
        s2.time as logout
        COALESCE(s2.time, NOW()) as not_null_logout
 FROM SIPregistration s1
 LEFT JOIN SIPregistration s2  -- I assume there are some SIP without logout
   ON s1.soip =s2.sip
  AND s1.time > s2.time
 -- WHERE s2.time IS NOT NULL  -- optional
```

Now found out if the SIP range overlap with your time window

```
SELECT s1.sip,
       s1.time as login
       s2.time as logout       
FROM SIPregistration s1
LEFT JOIN SIPregistration s2
  ON s1.soip =s2.sip
 AND s1.time > s2.time
WHERE s1.time < '11:00:00' 
  AND s2.time > '10:00:00' -- sip without logout wont show becasue s2.time is NULL.
```

Answer (score 0):

The  final query should look like this:

```
SELECT sip, `date`
min(time) as login, 
IF(max(time) != min(time), max(time), 'Not Logged Yet In This Range') as logout,
IF(max(time) != min(time), TIMEDIFF(max(time), min(time)), 'Not Logged Yet In This Range') as connected
From words
WHERE time between '10:00:00' and '11:00:00' 
GROUP BY sip;
```

You can change the text in if clause with what you want.
We just check if the max of time equal the min in the specific range you have in where clause

```
IF(expression ,expr_true, expr_false);
DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2); the interval not required
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer, to make it clear for other users.